# Show off-topic reasons for currently selected site instead of Software Engineering

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Let's say I'm [creating a new SEDE query for Meta Stack Exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/new). The `CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes` table has a nice 'show contents' icon, which saves me from having to execute `SELECT * FROM CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes`:

[image]

but when you click it, you always see the contents of the table on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

[image]

I'd like for it to show the contents from the database of the currently selected site.

<sub>Another table which has this problem is `PostNoticeTypes`, though it's less severe here; there are a few sites like [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com), [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) and [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) which have their own custom post notices.</sub>